# How to remove a session variable in jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to remove a session variable or set it to null in JSTL. Please help me with it.
If I have tried using

```
<c:set var="varialbleName" value=null scope="session" />
```

But it gives me the following **server error**.

```
Server Error
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsps/forum.jsp (line: 78, column: 71) quote symbol expected
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:276)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:223)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:163)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:154)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1231)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1453)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1666)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:996)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1271)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1453)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"gives me server error"_? Post the exact error.

Comment: I have added the error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove session variable by using following line of code:

```
<c:remove var="variableName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Session Scope use c remove tag of Jstl

```
<c:remove var="var_name" scope="session" />
```